# AngularJS, animations with ui router which versions work?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

There have been some incompatibilities with `ngAnimate` and `ui.router` since the release of Angular 1.2.

Which versions of Angular, Angular Animate and Angular UI Router work together?

Comment: Getting the same issue

Comment: ui router FAQ : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate

Comment: I'm going to try to push out 0.3 next week, which will support 1.0.8, 1.1.5, and 1.2.x, with full animation support.

Comment: Thanks Nate, what are the historical combinations that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following versions appear to be compatible (installed through bower):

```
{
  "angular": "1.2.3",
  "angular-ui-router": "0.2.0",
  "angular-animate": "1.2.3"
}
```

I'll update this list as I discover more combinations.

Comment: I used angular 1.1.5 and ui-router 0.2.0 in the past.  I upgraded to ui-router to 0.2.7 but stayed in angular 1.1.5 at the moment and animation is working fine for me.