# angular version 1.3.x doesn't seem to work with angular-ui-router 0.2.15

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I tried working on the following plunker example which works fine with angular version 1.2.x.

> But when the angular version is updated from 1.2.x to 1.3.x.
> It does not seem to work.
>
> The views does not seem to change when I click on the other tab.
>
> http://plnkr.co/edit/nmTggEdWIcMW5bMRKiok?p=preview

The following change was made to the plunker.

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

When tried on the chrome, there were no errors generated on the browser console but the views did not change when clicked on the second tab. Browser used Chrome-latest-version.

Might be a duplicate of
[AngularJS, animations with ui router which versions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991255/angularjs-animations-with-ui-router-which-versions-work)

PS:  I tried different combination of the bootstrap versions and angular-ui-router versions with angular 1.3.x. Was not able to find a successful combination. I use angular-material-design which requires angularjs version to be 1.3.x.  Any help on this issue would be appreciated.